# Beginning Python: Find greatest number from function that gives input list of positive integers

Tags: python

1. New to python, having trouble getting the function to display the greatest number, for some reason I have the number display the least. 
   The quiz I am using used this code as the final solution, I think it is wrong, any help appreciated.

   ```
   # Define a procedure, greatest,
   # that takes as input a list
   # of positive numbers, and
   # returns the greatest number
   # in that list. If the input
   # list is empty, the output
   # should be 0.
   def greatest(list_of_numbers):
       big = 0 
       for i in list_of_numbers: 
           if i > big: 
               big = i
           return big 

   print greatest([4,23,1])
   #>>> 23  I can't get 23 It returns 4 for some reason. 
   print greatest([])
   #>>> 0
   ```

   For some reason it gives me 4 instead of 23 as the greatest.

Comment: In python, indentation matters. Since `return big` is in your loop, it will return the first value larger than `0`, ie. `4`. Move the `return big` left by 1 tab ;)

Comment: Perfect, never had that problem until now, thanks for that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning on the first iteration. Move your return out one level:

```
def greatest(list_of_numbers):
    big = 0 
    for i in list_of_numbers: 
        if i > big: 
            big = i
    return big
```

However this is entirely unnecessary as Python has this built in:

```
def greatest(list_of_numbers):
    return max(list_of_numbers)
```